# Jekyll Layout Error When Using Pagination with Collections (jekyll-paginate-v2)

Tags: pagination, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to paginate a portfolio with `jekyll-paginate-v2` but I'm getting unexpected output.

In my `_config.yml`, I've got the following:

```yaml
collections:
  portfolio:
    output: true

pagination:
  enabled: true
  per_page: 6
  permalink: '/page-:num/'
  title: ':title — Page :num'
  sort_reverse: true
  trail:
    before: 6
    after: 6
```

I have a page, `portfolio.html`, which has the following frontmatter:

```yaml
---
layout: default
title: Portfolio
pagination:
  enabled: true
  collection: portfolio
  per_page: 9
---
```

That page is pulling the correct data from `_portfolio`, but it is using the `for` loop from `blog.html`. It doesn't matter if I add a `for` loop in the body of `portfolio.html` or leave the body blank.

The pagination is working as expected, but the layout is wrong. The debug output has no indication for layout used:

```
Pagination: ----------------------------
Pagination: Page: portfolio.html
Pagination:  Active configuration
Pagination:   Enabled:          true
Pagination:   Items per page:   9
Pagination:   Permalink:        /page-:num/
Pagination:   Title:            :title — Page :num
Pagination:   Limit:            0
Pagination:   Sort by:          date
Pagination:   Sort reverse:     true
Pagination:  Active Filters
Pagination:   Collection:       portfolio
Pagination:   Offset:           0
Pagination:   Category:         [Not set]
Pagination:   Tag:              [Not set]
Pagination:   Locale:           [Not set]
Pagination:  Filtering by: Category   10 => 10
Pagination:  Filtering by: Tag        10 => 10
Pagination:  Filtering by: Locale     10 => 10
Pagination: Rolling through the date fields for all documents
Pagination: Complete, processed 2 pagination page(s)
---
```

If I delete the `blog.html` file, the `for` loop in `portfolio.html` works as expected. If I enable autopages for collections it works as expected. However, as best as I can tell, this will restrict me to one `for` loop for all collections.

Is there anyway to get a `for` loop to work for collections without autopages?

Comment: Did you find any fix on this?

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution for my use-case, but it's not ideal. The layouts for autopages is an array, but I can't find documentation on using more than one.